# Google Cloud Storage download file using only React

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-storage

I am new member here in stack overflow. Hopefully, my question would be a valid one and in terms with the community.
I am trying to upload/download files from react app to GCP bucket. However, after looking around for long, I could not find a solution that actually tells how to upload/download from from react app to GCP bucket. All libraries, even in GCP documentation are in server based technology. My requirement is from client app(react) we can connect to GCP storage for the operation. I want to mention, I need that to work from react not any server based technology usage

I could not find a way to handle the things. Somehow I get to know that if it can be connected with firebase then we can access the GCP files. But again this is not what is expected, as there is no scope for firebase configuration. Also there are JSON APIs through which we can call directly the URL but then there has to be some kind of authentication. I however have the credentials to work for GCP, but could not actually understand how to use that incase this URL call works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to club the ReactJS front-end with NodeJS back-end and use Google SDK for NodeJS. https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest

Comment: s basically it is nt pssible without a server side technlogy involvement, is it?

Comment: Yes, Thats correct.